# Searching for a good book on count data

Tags: references, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, poisson-regression

I am seeking recommendations for a good book on count data, with clear explanations of topics like Poisson regression.

The level of the book should be suitable for a graduate math and statistics degree.

Comment: Welcome to our site! I am not sure if a similar question has been asked in the past. I suggest you click on the "references" tag I added and search within it for terms of interest to you, such as "count" or "Poisson regression". The obvious answer to your question is probably Agresti.

Comment: I think this question is not "primarily opinion-baser": we have an entire `[references]` tag for similar recommendation questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One book which could be a good, modern start is:   "Discrete Data Analysis with R: Visualization and Modeling Techniques for Categorical and Count Data (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science)" by Michael Friendly and  David Meyer.   It covers many different techniques and models with some theory.  A more theoretical (and more expensive!) book is "Econometric Analysis of Count Data" by Rainer Winkelmann.

An alternative is "Negative Binomial Regression 2nd Edition" by Joseph M. Hilbe which is more specialized than the first book above.

A simpler, more basic introduction (also cheaper) than the three books above is "Modeling Count Data 1st Edition" by Joseph M. Hilbe.

Comment: I read: "Modeling Count Data" by Joseph M.Hilbe.  It gave me All the basic knowledge I needed, Thanks!